# Are pages in sitefinity iSecurable?

Tags: c#, sitefinity

I'm trying to modify the permissions on a page programmatically. Are pages iSecurable, and is there such a thing as a PagesManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, There is a PageManager and the PageNode is ISecuredObject.

You can check the documentation here:

http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-permissions-api